# ITextSharp insert text to an existing pdf bottom of last page

Tags: asp.net, itext

Need help please.
Using asp.net how can I add text to an exisiting pdf but to the last page? The number of pages in the pdf isn't fixed.
This is what I have so far but it adds the text to the first page.

```
   Dim PdfContentByte As PdfContentByte = stamp.GetOverContent(1)
                Dim BaseFont As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
                                   PdfContentByte.BeginText()
                PdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, MsgOnClosing, 400, 600, 0)
                 PdfContentByte.EndText()
```

Comment: *"the first page"* - you use `stamp.GetOverContent(1)`. `1` is the number of the first page. Use the number of the last page instead.

Comment: Thanks. I got the location i wanted